# Why does the nltk stopwords output does not match nltk word_tokenize output

Tags: python, text, nltk, tokenize, cpu-word

I am currently using nltks stopwords and word_tokenize to process some text and encountered some weird behavior.

```
sentence = "this is a test sentence which makes perfectly.sense. doesn't it? it won't. i'm annoyed"
tok_sentence = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tok_sentence)
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

printing the following:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'sentence', 'which', 'makes', 'perfectly.sense', '.', 'does', "n't", 'it', '?', 'it', 'wo', "n't", '.', 'i', "'m", 'annoyed']

['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', "you're", "you've", "you'll", "you'd", 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 'she', "she's", 'her', 'hers', 'herself', 'it', "it's", 'its', 'itself', 'they', 'them', 'their', 'theirs', 'themselves', 'what', 'which', 'who', 'whom', 'this', 'that', "that'll", 'these', 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'be', 'been', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 'do', 'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'because', 'as', 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at', 'by', 'for', 'with', 'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 'through', 'during', 'before', 'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 'out', 'on', 'off', 'over', 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 'will', 'just', 'don', "don't", 'should', "should've", 'now', 'd', 'll', 'm', 'o', 're', 've', 'y', 'ain', 'aren', "aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", 'didn', "didn't", 'doesn', "doesn't", 'hadn', "hadn't", 'hasn', "hasn't", 'haven', "haven't", 'isn', "isn't", 'ma', 'mightn', "mightn't", 'mustn', "mustn't", 'needn', "needn't", 'shan', "shan't", 'shouldn', "shouldn't", 'wasn', "wasn't", 'weren', "weren't", 'won', "won't", 'wouldn', "wouldn't"]
```

Focusing on the words containing the " ' "-char. We can see, that the stopword list clearly contains words separated by it. At the same time all the words in my sample sentence are included in the stopword list, so are its parts. ("doesn't" -> included, "doesn" + "t" -> included).

The word_tokenize function however splits the word "doesn't" into "does" and "n't".
Filtering the stopwords after using word_tokenize will therefore lead to the removal of "does" but leaves "n't" behind...

I was wondering if this behavior was intentional. If so, could someone please explain why?

Comment: I don't know if the behaviour is intentional. You could filter stopwords before doing tokenization. n't would not be left behind.

Comment: thx @Michael_H for the reply, i solved the issue by removing the " ' " char, the stopwords will do the rest then, i still find this kind of weird though.